# blockfrost.io API, reference inputs and redeemer tx_index

Tags: blockfrost, redeemer, plutus-v2

AIUI, when using the blockfrost.io API, the `tx_index` field in a redeemer contains the index of the enclosing transaction's input that it consumes (is that true ?).

However, with reference inputs, it seems that in this API the reference inputs and "regular" inputs are all merged in the transaction's `utxos.inputs` list.

In that case, it looks the `tx_index` field in the redeemer no longer matches the index of the referenced input in the `inputs` list, but rather the position of the Nth *non-reference* input in the list.

Example:

- without reference inputs:

```
utxos.inputs = [i1,i2,i3]`
redeemer.tx_index=2
```

In that case, the redeemer points at `i3`

- with reference inputs (marked as `ri`):

```
utxos.inputs = [ri1, ri2, i1,i2,i3]`
redeemer.tx_index=2
```

In that case, the redeemer *also* points at `i3` because the reference inputs are ignored in the indexing.

Can someone confirm that this understanding is correct, or provide the correct way of interpreting the redeemer's `tx_index` field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AIUI, when using the blockfrost.io API, the `tx_index` field in a redeemer contains the index of the enclosing transaction's input that it consumes (is that true ?).

The index holds different meaning for different purposes. For instance, if minting policies are involved in a transaction, index for a particular minting policy would be it's position in lexicographic ordering of the involved minting policies. For more information, see `indexOf` function in [Alonzo ledger documentation](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-ledger/releases/latest/download/alonzo-ledger.pdf). So, if you are only looking for indexes where `purpose` in response is set to `spend` then your understanding of `tx_index` is correct.

Now any output which is inside [`transaction_input`](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-ledger/blob/642b86e3263a5ffdc43b89b0b4130475c309e1a2/eras/babbage/test-suite/cddl-files/babbage.cddl#L54) then it is indeed getting consumed by the transaction (if it is of course successful), reference input(s) cannot be inside this `transaction_input` list. Provider's might mention it in input(s) but then they would also mention whether it's a reference input (in which case you can ignore it) or not. So, yes, your understanding on ignoring reference input(s) to determine for index is correct.